# Broken precompiled assets in Rails 3.1 when deploying to a sub-URI

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline, passenger, assets, sprockets

I'm in the process of updating a Rails 3 app to use Rails 3.1 and as part of that, am making use of the new asset pipeline. So far, I've got everything working apart from one rather annoying problem I can't solve.

The application and all its assets works fine in development, but in production it is deployed to a sub-URI using Passenger (`http://the-host/sub-uri/`). The problem with this is that the assets are pre-compiled during deployment and one of my CSS (well, it's a `.css.scss` file) files is making use of the `image-url` helper from the `sass-rails` gem. Since during the pre-compilation process, the paths are hard-coded into the precompiled CSS file, the sub-uri is not taken account of:

In my `.css.scss` file:

```
body { background-image: image-url("bg.png"); }
```

The result in the compiled `application-<md5-hash-here>.css` file:

```
body { background-image: url(/assets/bg.png); }
```

What it should be to make it work correctly:

```
body { background-image: url(/sub-uri/assets/bg.png); }
```

Is this scenario just asking too much? If so, I'll have to switch back to the old non-asset-pipelined way and just serve my images and CSS from `public`. However it seems like something which should have been thought about and solved...? Am I missing the solution?

---

**Edit 1:** I should note that using the [erb solution](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-erb) instead yields the same result, as one would expect.

---

**Edit 2: in response to Benoit Garret's comment**

No, the problem isn't related to the `config.assets.prefix`. I tried setting that (to `/sub-uri/assets` rather than the default of `/assets`) but it turned out that was the wrong thing to do - it seems like this setting is already in relation to the root of the Rails app, not the server. Removing that (and thus returning to the default) has fixed all the weird issues that caused (and there were many, all the assets ended up in `/sub-uri/sub-uri/assets` - it was all very strange). The only problem is that the `image-url` helper and friends do not pick up the sub-URI when they are pre-compiled. Needless to say, this is logical since when it is pre-compiled, it couldn't possibly know that when it's running under Passenger, it'll be configured in this way. My question is how to inform it of this and thus end up with the correct paths in the precompiled result. If indeed it can be done.

My current workaround is to reference the iamge in the CSS like this: `url(../images/bg.png)` and place it in the non-pipelined `public/images` location. Hardly ideal since it doesn't benefit from the fingerprinting and everything which the pipeline provides.

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295744/how-to-deploy-rails-3-1-app-in-a-subdirectory

Comment: The app itself is deployed fine (it does use that RailsBaseURI method as it is what passengers docs recommend). All the assets linked to from within the running application like images using `image_tag` and so on are fine. the only problem is the images referred to from within the CSS - it does not know about the sub-URI at time of pre-compilation of the assets. It is that for which I need a solution if there is one.

Comment: So your problem is that the `image-uri` helper doesn't pick up `config.assets.prefix`?

Comment: Not exactly, no. See my latest question edit for a more detailed response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I've worked out a couple of workarounds/solutions.

1) From https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/17 it looks like this could get fixed in sass-rails.  I've monkey-patched helpers.rb myself along the lines of the proposed patch in the link above.  I simply set the required environment variable in the asset precompile line in `deploy.rb`.

I do all my monkey patching in a single file `config/initializers/gem_patches.rb`.  In this file I patched this method as:

```
module Sass
  module Rails
    module Helpers
      protected
      def public_path(asset, kind)
        path = options[:custom][:resolver].public_path(asset, kind.pluralize)
        path = ENV['PRODUCTION_URI'] + path if ENV['PRODUCTION_URI']
        path
      end
    end
  end
end
```

2) Alternatively if you are ok to embed images in the CSS, changing the stylesheet to have a .erb extension, and replacing the `image-url("bg.png")` with `url(<%= asset_data_uri "bg.png" %>)` will work without any need to change sass-rails.  `asset-data-uri` doesn't exist as a pure Sass function so you have to use the Rails helper `asset_data_uri`.

Comment: Good shout on the second point - that would work and it's something I never considered. Definitely less than desirable, but a valid workaround. For point 1, could you clarify the setting of the variable in `deploy.rb` please?

Comment: I've just worked out what you mean... you're manually running the precompile task from your deploy.rb file, right? I'm using the supplied one by having added `load 'deploy/assets'` to my Capfile - so there's nowhere obvious in `deploy.rb` where I should put the environment variable setting. I'm sure I can find somewhere else to set it though. Even at worst, you've given me an issue to keep an eye on, at best I think it's the answer for right now. Thanks :)

Comment: Exactly.  In my `deploy.rb` I have the asset precompile in an `after "deploy:update_code"` task.  I do `run "cd #{release_path}; bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production PRODUCTION_URI='/myapp'"` and then in my monkey-patched helpers.rb I just pick up `ENV['PRODUCTION_URI']`.

Comment: How (well where) did you do your monkey-patching? I seem to be failing with mine.

Comment: Hi Mark, I've expanded my answer above with details of the patch.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. That's a good plan. I was tagging it on the end of things like environment.rb. Felt wrong - this is much better. (Btw, tweaked the answer a bit: `Saas` -> `Sass`. :)

Answer (score 2):

In the latest Rails 3.1.3 you need to monkey patch a different module now, for it to work

This is what I did

```
module Sprockets
  module Helpers
    module RailsHelper

      def asset_path(source, options = {})
        source = source.logical_path if source.respond_to?(:logical_path)
        path = asset_paths.compute_public_path(source, asset_prefix, options.merge(:body => true))
        path = options[:body] ? "#{path}?body=1" : path
        if !asset_paths.send(:has_request?)
          path = ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT'] + path if ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT']
        end
        path
      end

    end 
  end
end
```

And in my deploy.rb I have:

```
desc "precompile the assets"
namespace :assets do
  task :precompile_assets do
    run "cd #{release_path} && rm -rf public/assets/* && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT='/my_sub_uri'"
  end
end
before "deploy:symlink", "assets:precompile_assets"
```

Comment: thanks. and I found that in Rails 3.2 we don't need the patch. just run command `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT='/my_sub_uri'"` and it works

Comment: Thanks @SiweiShen, for capistrano I added a task in deploy.rb to run before deploy:assets:precompile, which did 'set :asset_env, "#{asset_env} RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT=/my_sub_uri"'

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Rails 3.1.3 and deploying to a sub-URI successfully.
I have NOT monkey-patched anything.

The key problems with this setup have been better discussed [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3259). As you can see, the solution was applied to Rails 3.2 and never backPorted to 3.1.4.

But, I have came to a **solution using Rails 3.1.3** that works for my setup.

**Try this:**  *(I'm no expert, just trying to contribute to solve a problem that hassled me for hours...)*

environment.rb:

```
#at top:
ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT'] = '/rais'
```

production.rb:

```
config.assets.prefix = ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT'] ? ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT'] + '/assets' : '/assets'
```

routes.rb:

```
  Rais::Application.routes.draw do
       scope ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT'] || '/' do    #see config/environment.rb
             <<resources here>>
       end
  end
```

As you can see, I've put assets.prefix inside production.rb, not in application.rb
After that you do:

```
rake assets:clear
rake assets:precompile
```

and than, test with the console:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails console
```

Results:

```
foo = ActionView::Base.new
foo.stylesheet_link_tag 'application'
 => "<link href=\"/rais/assets/layout.css?body=1\" media=\"screen\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" />\n<link href=\"/rais/assets/application.css?body=1\" media=\"screen\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" />" 
foo.image_tag('arrow-up.png')
 => "<img alt=\"Arrow-up\" src=\"/rais/assets/arrow-up-ca314ad9b991768ad2b9dcbeeb8760de.png\" />"
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of digging around, I have found the issue. The issue is in Rails, specifically Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper::AssetPaths#compute_public_path. Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper::AssetPaths inherits from ActionView::AssetPaths and overrides a number of methods. When compute_public_path is called through the Sass::Rails::Resolver#public_path method is sass-rails, the rails sprocket helper picks up the task of resolving the asset. Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper::AssetPaths#compute_public_path defers to super which is ActionView::AssetPaths#compute_public_path. In this method there is a condition of has_request? on rewrite_relative_url_root as seen below:

```
def compute_public_path(source, dir, ext = nil, include_host = true, protocol = nil)
  ...
  source = rewrite_relative_url_root(source, relative_url_root) if has_request?
  ...
end

def relative_url_root
  config = controller.config if controller.respond_to?(:config)
  config ||= config.action_controller if config.action_controller.present?
  config ||= config
  config.relative_url_root
end
```

If you look at the internals of rewrite_relative_url_root it relies on a request to be present and the ability to derive it from the controller variable in order to resolve the relative url root. The issue is that when sprockets resolves these assets for sass it does not have a controller present and therefore no request.

The solution above didn't work in development mode for me. Here is the solution that I am using to make it work for now:

```
module Sass
  module Rails
    module Helpers
      protected
      def public_path(asset, kind)
        resolver = options[:custom][:resolver]
        asset_paths = resolver.context.asset_paths
        path = resolver.public_path(asset, kind.pluralize)
        if !asset_paths.send(:has_request?) && ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT']
          path = ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT'] + path
        end
        path
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Am I right in thinking this is essentially the same fix as the other answer, but implemented just a little differently? (perhaps a little less naively, not that the other approach caused me any issues...)