# How to deploy Rails 3.1 app in a subdirectory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I configure a Rails 3.1 application to run under a specific directory such as "/r"?

I tried in config.ru:

```
map '/r' do
    run Debtor::Application
end
```

but that just returned "Not Found: /r"

To get it to work I had to enclose all routes in a scope:

```
scope '/r' do 
    #routes
end
```

and to add the following line to config/applcation.rb

```
config.assets.prefix = "/r/assets"
```

and to move my jquery ui css files from /stylesheets to /r/stylesheets.

this seems too complicated. isn't there an easier way? and why isn't my config.ru setting working?

my use case is to have a rails powered ajax backend for a wordpress server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

are you running under passenger?

Then RailsBaseURI is probably what you want.

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/apache/deploy/ruby/#deploying-an-app-to-a-sub-uri

If not running under passenger, please update your question to show what you are deployed under.

Comment: thank you for the response. yes, i am using passenger. i am looking for a simpler solution.

Comment: Simplier than 1 line in your apache configuration file?  I not sure you can get much simplier than that. Sorry I confused.

Comment: How can I do this with just a 1 line configuration? It seems to me that I need to create a symlink from the subpath in the document root to the rails project public directory as well.

Comment: Actually you don't need to create a symlink you, can just map that directory in directly in apache. I meant 1 extra line in the standard passenger configuration block you would need for apache regardless.

Comment: What wasn't apparently obvious from these docs however was that you need to pass a variable to your asset precompilation rake task, so that it generates the correct sub-uri into your assets:

rake assets:precompile RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT=/foo

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was creating the symbolic link for the sub-uri (/info) to the 'public' folder of the application (setup under another user on my server, /home/otheruser/current/public).

```
ln -s /home/myapp/current/public /home/mysite/public_html/info
```

Then I inserted this configuration inside of the VirtualHost entry for the site:

```
Alias /info /home/myapp/current/public
<Location /info>
  PassengerAppRoot /home/myapp/current
  RackEnv production
  RackBaseURI /info
</Location>
```

No scoped routes, no asset prefix configuration.

Comment: Best answer yet! I'd up this answer again if I could :)

Comment: Right.. This is the cleanest solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Here’s how to deploy a Rails 3.1 app to a subdirectory in Apache, replacing `config.action_controller.relative_url_root` which no longer exists.

In `config/routes.rb`:

```
scope 'my_subdir' do
  # all resources and routes go here
end
```

In your Apache configuration file:

```
Alias /my_subdir /var/www/my_subdir/public
<Location /my_subdir>
  SetEnv RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT "/my_subdir"
  PassengerAppRoot /var/www/my_subdir
</Location>
```

And it should work, including automatically pointing all your assets to `/my_subdir`.

Comment: will this really work for assets and files in the public directory?

Comment: It will work when your assets are in the `app/assets` folder. But it _should_ also work for assets and files in the public directory because of the `Alias` keyword pointing the folder directly down in your public folder. Please let me know if it works.