# anchor and refinery cms menu incorrect routing for sub uri

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache2, passenger, refinerycms

I have developed the ruby on rails application and am trying to deploy it using apache-passenger sub uri by referring this [link](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#RackBaseURI). images, css and javascripts are working without any issues. But anchor tag and refinery cms other menu tabs are not working.

My anchor tag code is

```
<a href=<%= "#{request.env['HTTP-HOST']}/product_details/gotoLink/#{p1}/#{p2}" %> target="_blank" id="zoomid"></a>
```

I have mounted refinery cms on '/admin'. When I access it using http://mydomain.com/suburi, it will successfully logs in but when I click on menus like pages, files and etc I will get 404 error.

The same application will works fine without sub uri. Please Any one help me to fix this problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I referred this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295744/how-to-deploy-rails-3-1-app-in-a-subdirectory) url and issue is got fixed by doing the below changes

I solved first problem like this

```
rake RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT=/suburi assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

RAILSapp -> config -> environments -> production.rb

```
config.action_controller.relative_url_root = ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT']
```

In views I did like this

```
<a href=<%= "#{request.env['HTTP-HOST']}#{ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT']}/product_details/#{p1}/#{p2}" %> target="_blank" id="zoomid" >Link Name</a>
```

For refinery I have added app->views->refinery->admin->_menu.html.erb

```
<%= link_to plugin.title, refinery.url_for("#{ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT']}#{plugin.url}"),:class => ("active" if plugin.highlighted?(params)),:id => "plugin_#{plugin.name}" %>
```

and in app -> views -> refinery -> _site_bar.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Home", "#{ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT']}" -%>
```

My issues is got fixed. If this is not right approach then please tell me the right approach

Thanks