# Rails asset pipeline, sub-URI deployment with path prefix, image_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have a Rails 3.1 application.

I am deploying it via passenger to a *SubURI*, not to URI root. For instance, the app root is actually accessed as http://somewhere.com/application .

I have a stylesheet.css.erb in my app using the asset pipeline, that sets a background-image with

```
<%= asset_path 'something.gif' %>
```

However, when I run `rake assets:precompile`, it precompiles this to `/assets/something.gif`, not `/application/assets/something.gif` -- because when I'm running the rake task from the command line, it doesn't yet know about the path prefix ("/application") that's going to be operative when running under Passenger at a SubURI.

What's the right way to handle this?  Is there a way to tell the assets:precompile task to use a particular path prefix, because we know when precompiling that we're actually going to deploy to a path prefix?

- note: The path's generated by the actual live app, for instance `stylesheet_link_tag 'application'` in the layout, **do** generate properly with the path prefix. So the asset pipeline does respect the path prefix when it's operative. The problem is clearly that when I run assets:precompile, it's got no way of knowing what the ultimate prefix is going to be, the way I'm running it. How do I tell it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has come up before:
Seems to be a limitation in Sprockets that is now merged into master:
https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/2977

I guess you need to set the `RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT`

Sources:

- [Broken precompiled assets in Rails 3.1 when deploying to a sub-URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293918/broken-precompiled-assets-in-rails-3-1-when-deploying-to-a-sub-uri)
- [Rails 3.1 SASS asset helpers not not including RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT / relative_url_root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363733/rails-3-1-sass-asset-helpers-not-not-including-rails-relative-url-root-relativ)

Comment: Huh, but that will not work in 3.1 release, I need to run rails/sprockets off an unreleased version? Bah. Is it included in the 3.2, or will it not even be in 3.2?

Comment: I accepted your answer to give you the karma, because your links led me to the solution, although this answer isn't complete or entirely accurate. See my self answer on this question at http://stackoverflow.com/a/8822692/307106

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I guess maybe I'll accept @Tigraine's to give him the karma, as he LED me to the solution.

Just setting RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT is **not** enough however in current *released* Rails 3.1.3 (it might be in master) -- it won't do anything. You need to actually monkey patch Rails to add this feature.

What I actually ended up doing is a modified version of the solution given in one of the answers he pointed to. I use alias_method_chain to monkey patch copy-and-pasting as little of existing Rails logic as possible:  https://gist.github.com/1595405

@Tigraine suggests there's a fix in master, I haven't confirmed this. If so, I have no idea what release of rails it's slated for (next 3.1.x, 3.2, even later?), or exactly what form it will take (RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT)?  If anyone knows the answer to these, perhaps in the future when such a version is released, please add a comment or answer.